# Swift How to make the previous label disappear and the new one to appear

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I’m making my first project that is a truth or dare game but when I tap the button to print a Truth/dare the labels are getting stacked on each other. How do I make it that the previous label disappear and the new one is there alone. Thanks in advance

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

public class ViewController: UIViewController {
    public override func loadView() {
        //adding baground
        super.loadView()
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view = view
        //dare button
        let dareButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:300, y: 500, width: 100, height: 69))
        dareButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        dareButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6352941393852234, green: 0.6470588445663452, blue: 0.886274516582489, alpha: 1.0)
        dareButton.setTitle("dare", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        dareButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        dareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dareButtonDidTap), for: .touchDown)
        view.addSubview(dareButton)
        self.view = view
        view.addSubview(dareButton)
    }
    @objc
    private func dareButtonDidTap() {
        let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:95 , y:100, width: 325, height: 500))
        lbl.text = daresEng.randomElement()
        lbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6313725709915161, green: 0.6470588445663452, blue: 0.9058823585510254, alpha: 1.0)
        lbl.numberOfLines = 6
        view.addSubview(lbl)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels are stacked because you create a new label and add it to the view each time you click the `dareButton`, and the previous labels are not removed from the `superView`. So you can move the label to the class level and add it to the view in `loadView()`. This way you only have one label, and in the `dareButtonDidTap()`, you only have to change the text of this label.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

public class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:95 , y:100, width: 325, height: 500))
    
    public override func loadView() {
        //adding baground
        super.loadView()
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view = view
        //dare button
        let dareButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:300, y: 500, width: 100, height: 69))
        dareButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        dareButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6352941393852234, green: 0.6470588445663452, blue: 0.886274516582489, alpha: 1.0)
        dareButton.setTitle("dare", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        dareButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        dareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dareButtonDidTap), for: .touchDown)
        view.addSubview(dareButton)
        self.view = view
        
        view.addSubview(lbl)
        view.addSubview(dareButton)
    }
    
    @objc
    private func dareButtonDidTap() {
        lbl.text = daresEng.randomElement()
        lbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6313725709915161, green: 0.6470588445663452, blue: 0.9058823585510254, alpha: 1.0)
        lbl.numberOfLines = 6

    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```